# AJAX POST not working to load div view in CODEIGNITER

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Help me out with my ajax thing...Alright what i am trying to do is i have a side column navigation panel in may main view..all the navigation links is fetched from database.now what i want is when i click any link it should load the CI view div in the same main view but in the middle panel and if  click  second link it should replace the old view div with new one without loading page.The Divs to be loaded after click are placed in the views folder of the project(CI views folder).
Now what i have tried is when link is clicked i call the ajax with the view name passes as the data to the URL(/controller/method) and controller load the view and on ajax success the view should be loaded in the middle panel as the new div.

View Code:

script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $("a.links").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        alert("alert on click");
        var platform_id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(platform_id);


        $.ajax({

             url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/load_view', 
             type: 'POST',
             datatype:'json',
             data: {'view_param': platform_id},
             success: function(response)
             {
                 if (response.success == 1)
                    {
                       alert('success');
                    }
                    else{
                    alert('unseccessful');   //just a alert to see if response is successful              
                    }       
             },
             error: function(response){
                    alert(response.message);
                }

        }); 


        })
        })

        </script>


<div id="left-column">
          <h3>Header</h3>
          <ul class="nav">
         <?php foreach($ops as $operations)
            {$op_name = $operations['admin_op'];
             $op_link = $operations['link_to'];
        ?>  

        <li><a href="" id="<?php echo $op_name ; ?>" class="links"><?php echo $op_name ;?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
      </ul>
          <a href="http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/" class="link">Link here</a> <a href="http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/" class="link">Link here</a> 
          </div>
```

middle panel div:

```
<div id="mang_server"> </div>
```

Controller code:

```
public function load_view(){

$view_name = $this->input->post('view_param');
log_message('var dump', var_export($view_name));
$data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name);
$response['html_view'] = $this->load->view($data['view_link'],'',TRUE);
echo json_encode($response);
//$this->load->view($data);
}
```

I tried to debug it also i observe that it goes success portion of the ajax but it alerts the else part of it.

error portion alert:

```
'Manage Servers'{"success":1,"message":"Some success message","html_view":"<table class=\"listing form\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n          <tr>\n            <th class=\"full\" colspan=\"2\">Header Here<\/th>\n          <\/tr>\n          <tr>\n            <td class=\"first\" width=\"172\"><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong><\/td>\n            <td class=\"last\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text\" \/><\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n          <tr class=\"bg\">\n            <td class=\"first\"><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong><\/td>\n            <td class=\"last\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text\" \/><\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n          <tr>\n            <td class=\"first\"><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong><\/td>\n            <td class=\"last\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text\" \/><\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n          <tr class=\"bg\">\n            <td class=\"first\"><strong>Lorem Ipsum<\/strong><\/td>\n            <td class=\"last\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"text\" \/><\/td>\n          <\/tr>\n        <\/table>\n        <p>&nbsp;<\/p>"}
```

Comment: alert response and check. Also can check the network request and response in developer tools.

Comment: change **`datatype:'json',`** to **`dataType:'json',`**.

Comment: post your **response** here too.

Comment: @IJas i tried your thing now it goes to the error portion of the ajax and alert me "undefined".

Comment: instead of `message` replace with this `alert(response.responseText);` are you able to see your ajax url in network tab is it correct?

Comment: Where is **`$response['success'] = 1;`** in your **controller** code ?  It seems you didn't assign that.

Comment: @Jai your alert(response.responseText); things work for me. Now it shoes me the complete response array include my view code(html).. can you please tell me why response is not successful.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your controller you didn't assigne **`$response['success']`** and **`$response['message']`** which you need in the front end. Change the **controller** code into,

```
public function load_view()
{
    $view_name = $this->input->post('view_param');
    log_message('var dump', var_export($view_name, true));
    $data['view_link'] = $this->admin_model->load_view_model($view_name);

    $response['success'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = "Some success message";
    $response['html_view'] = $this->load->view($data['view_link'],'',TRUE);
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}
```

Hope this helps :)

### Updated:

**NOTE:** in **`log_message('var dump', var_export($view_name, true));`**, **`var_export()`** need a second parameter to return the value. Otherwise, it will output a text and causes problem with your ajax response.

Comment: thanks for your help...i tried your think and it work to some extent but in ajax part it still goes to error portion and alerts me complete response array with my view code as response data.

Comment: help me understand why it is going to error portion when success = 1

Comment: Can you do this, inside **`success: function(response){  }`**, do a **`console.log(response)`** and post the log here ? I need to what the server sends back before go further.

Comment: but it is not going to the success portion  instead it is going to error.

Comment: is this url correct **`'<?php echo base_url() ?>admin/load_view'`** ? is your request sent to the server ? you can check this in the console.

Comment: yes URL is correct and the request also goes to server but...the response it should return in success it is returning me in error ..below i have posted the complete alert mesg.

Comment: Don't post it in the answer, you can edit your question. Delete the answer and edit the question.

Comment: Do comment this line, **`log_message('var dump', var_export($view_name));`**. it is echoing an additional text.

Comment: if you still need to use **`log_message()`** use it as **`log_message('var dump', var_export($view_name, true));`**, and you are welcome.

Comment: extremely sorry...new to stackoverflow as a user..need 15 reputation points for this.I will as soon as i am eligible.:-)